# Sublime Text 3: Move caret up/down between displayed lines

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

With soft-wrapping enabled, 1 text line could occupy multiple displayed lines -- depending on how wide the window is. By default Up/Down arrows move carets between actual lines. I was wondering whether there is a command to move caret up or down between the displayed lines?

FWIW in Vim they would be `gj` and `gk`.

Comment: Are you using any extra plugins? Vanilla Sublime Text 2 and 3 both do what you are describing right out of the box.

Comment: @NateMara How to do that with vanilla Sublime Text?